# Как вывести несколько разделов из каталога BITRIX?

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть каталог товаров, в нем есть разделы: 1,2,3,4, в каждом из этих разделов лежат товары. Нужно на отдельную страницу вывести разделы 1 и 3 из этого каталога. Может решение легкое, просто я новичек в битриксе и php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php не причём надо смотреть документацыю по bitrix api, если компонент для вывода каталога bitrix:catalog
(https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/catalog/catalog.php) у него есть "FILTER_NAME"
куда можно указать SECTION_ID = ..., если надо несколько то можно использовать сложную логику.
(у компонента bitrix:catalog мождет есть и SECTION_ID (в параметрах вызова компонента) но наверно только одно значение прокидывается)

Пример:

```
$arFilter = Array(
   Array(
       "LOGIC"=>"OR",
       Array(
           "SECTION_ID" => 1 // тут может быть IBLOCK_SECTION_ID
       ),
       Array(
           "SECTION_ID" => 3
       )
   )
);

...


'FILTER_NAME' => 'arFilter', // именно название переменной
...
```

(если каталог выводится другим компонентом там тоже может быть параметр "FILTER_NAME")

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно конкретные разделы выводить на странице, то предлагаю хороший способ:

1. Добавить к нужным разделам символьный код.
2. Добавить метод, который будет получать символьный код по ID раздела.
3. В параметры компонента прокидывать символьные коды нужных для отображение разделов.(Либо как вариант добавить св-во "Отображать на <такой-то странице>")
4. В компоненте/result_modifier прописать обработку данных получаемых разделов по параметрам переданным в компонент.